# CMAKE separate Linker and Compiler Flags

Tags: eclipse, cmake

Right now my `toolchain.cmake` looks loke this:

```
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
SET(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-as)
SET(CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy CACHE INTERNAL "objcopy" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump CACHE INTERNAL "objdump" FORCE)

# Compiler Flags 
SET(MCU_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb")
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_FLAGS "-O2 -g -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=soft -Wa,-meabi=5 -ffunction-sections -fno-common -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${MCU_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_BUILD_FLAGS}"  CACHE INTERNAL "c compiler flags")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} CACHE INTERNAL "cxx compiler flags")
SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "-g -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=soft -meabi=5 -warn" CACHE INTERNAL "asm compiler flags")

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -nostartfiles -Wl,-T1.ld,-M=1.map,--gc-sections" CACHE INTERNAL "exe link flags")
```

The problem is that CMake passes to the Linker additionally the Compiler-flags! Is there any way to separate these two?

Another thing is if I use another compiler-tool-chain (Like Fujitsu Softtune) how can I tell CMake explicitly to take a Linker and not the compiler to Link objects?

Thanks

---

So i finally solved it. for evryone else with the same problem, i changed CMakelists as follow:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C CXX ASM)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES  LINK_FLAGS "${LD_FLAGS_STR} -m ${PROJECT_NAME}.map")
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "FLNK907S.EXE  -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
```

and it works fine...

where `${LD_FLAGS_STR}` is just the list of my linker flags (own variable). and `LNK907S.EXE` is the name of Linker i 'm using (Fujitsu).

Comment: The answer here appears to require project specific settings. I have the same general issue and would rather not have to repeat these settings on each of the dozen libraries and binaries I'm trying to build.

Comment: Hi I upvoted. I was facing the same problem. The only question I have is, you have project specific settings. It would be great if you could post what the ${LD_FLAGS_STR} are and what the <TARGET><LINK_FLAGS><OBJECTS> are.
As I also want to reduce /delete the unused part of my code

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES` to set the link flags, respectively:

```
SET(MCU_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb")
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_FLAGS "-O2 -g -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=soft -Wa,-meabi=5 -ffunction-sections -fno-common -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${MCU_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_BUILD_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})
SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "-g -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=soft -meabi=5 -warn")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(FOO PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -nostartfiles -Wl,-T1.ld,-M=1.map,--gc-sections")
```

Here, I have assumed your excutable is called "FOO".  Note that the link libaries are specified on a per-target basis.  If you need special compiler flags for the target only, you can use `COMPILE_FLAGS` in `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES` as well.

Comment: i changed the CMakeLists as you said but the problem is still there. cmake call alway the same compiler for compiling and linking almost with the same flags!!!! as long as i compile and link with gcc there is no problem, but the fujitsu compiler and linker are completely diffrent (with diffrent flags)!!

Comment: its really frustrating there is no good documentation for cmake:(

Comment: In response to your first comment, if instead of using `SET_COMPILE_FLAG` you could try the `COMPILE_FLAGS` option to `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES`.  That might get you some true differentiation between compiler and linker.

Comment: What is this SET_COMPILE_FLAG()? It isn't present in the cmake documentation and I reports errors when I use it. I did find something like SET_COMPILE_FLAGS, a helper macro but this answer isn't solid if it makes use of macros that aren't present in cmake without referencing them...

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Yup, you are right.  It was a dumb copy/paste error on my part.  SET_COMPILE_FLAG is a macro I wrote within my project that does some extra work before doing `SET`.  I changed the code to `SET`.  It must have been late when I wrote this answer (I even had that stupid note about SET_COMPILE_FLAG!).

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of cmake, using generator expressions [1] has been my preferred approach.

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${C_DEFS} ${C_FLAGS}>
        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM>:${ASM_FLAGS}>)
```

[1] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html